# How to embed and execute a Javascript code inside a Javascript

Tags: javascript

My server is responding back with a json of javascript codes, which is somewhat like this :-

```
{
 "response":[   
        '<script type="text/javascript" class="around_track">var around_jp = around_jp || { "params" : new Array(), "complete_map" : new Object() };around_jp.params.push({"co_account_id" : "8957", "group_id" : "userlist97984", "country_id" : "1", "ver" : "1.1.0"});</script><script src="http://d-cache.vletik.jp/js/around_track_jp.js" type="text/javascript"></script>',

        '<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">var ask_div = document.createElement("div");ask_div.innerHTML = "<IFRAME id=\"id1\" src=\"http://image.ask.co.kr/lapex/vz_sc.html\" width=\"0\" Height=\"0\" style=\"display:none\"></IFRAME>";var c = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];c.parentNode.insertBefore(ask_div, c); </script>',

        "......
        and many more like this
        ....."

 ]
}
```

I am able to get the json response from server but now I want to execute these scripts from a javascript. How can i do that ??
I tried the following but it is not working.

```
 <script>   
        //code to get response json from server...
        var scriptPixelContainer=document.createElement("div");
        listOfScripts=JSON.parse(jsonResponse).response;
        for(var i=0;i<listOfScripts.length;i++){
            var newScriptPixel=document.createElement('script');
            newScriptPixel.type= 'text/javascript';
            newScriptPixel.text=listOfScripts[i];
            scriptPixelContainer.appendChild(newScriptPixel);

        }

        document.body.appendChild(scriptPixelContainer);    


</script>
```

Comment: can i ask why you are doing this? why not just include the scripts on the page you need them?

Comment: It is actually not clear why it is done like this..i have been assigned this task and the problem statement says that i have to do it in this manner.. @Craicerjack

Comment: I am fetching the json of scripts by making an ajax request to the server. I need to include each of these scripts to the main document. I was not able to think of anything else than going this way. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: It is similar to what i mentioned in my previous comment. 
1. Get a json by making an ajax request.
2. Parse the json and include each of the script into the document, so that each of the script can execute.

Comment: Invalid JSON error on JSONLint...

Comment: yup json is not properly formatted. It is just an example. I am able to get properly formatted valid json from server. The problem is how to put the scripts inside document so that they can execute.

Comment: Assuming above JSON file if you are getting response with <script> tag then why are creating new <script> tag element, you can directly append the response items to body.

Comment: directly appending will just add the script into the body, but it wont get executed. I tried it.

Answer (score 0):

Let me simplify: Imagine your script is only:

```
'<script type="text/javascript" class="around_track">alert("xisto");</script>'
```

To insert this into the body, you can use something like this:

```
const scriptContent = 'alert("xisto");';
const scriptElement = document.createElement('script');
scriptElement.type = 'text/javascript';
scriptElement.className = 'around_track';
scriptElement.textContent = scriptContent;

document.body.appendChild(scriptElement);
```

If you want to extract the className programmatically, you can use this:

```
const scriptString = '<script type="text//javascript" class="around_track">alert("xisto");<//script>';

const classNameRegex = /class="([^"]+)"/;
const classNameMatch = scriptString.match(classNameRegex);
const className = classNameMatch ? classNameMatch[1] : '';

const contentRegex = />([^<]+)</;
const contentMatch = scriptString.match(contentRegex);
const scriptContent = contentMatch ? contentMatch[1] : '';

const scriptElement = document.createElement('script');
scriptElement.type = 'text/javascript';
scriptElement.className = className;
scriptElement.textContent = scriptContent;

document.body.appendChild(scriptElement);
```

In this example, I used two regular expressions:

**classNameRegex**: Extracts the class value from the string. The expression /class="([^"]+)"/ captures the content within quotes after the word class.

**contentRegex**: Extracts the script content from the string. The expression />([^<]+)</ captures the content between the greater than and less than signs.

Some improvements can be made to the regular expressions depending on how well-behaved the input is.